# Firebase+GTM SDK - logging events to Google Analytics without specifying the screenName field

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

When tracking mobile apps events in Google Analytics (using Firebase+GTM SDK), is it required to specify screenName field for the event hit or GA will do aligning automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the screenName field reference in your UA tag if you want to do analysis with this dimension in GA.

For a screen view you have to configure your tag as following :

Tag : GA (Universal Analytics)
Type : Page view
Reference field : screenName (you map your Firebase screen name parameter here)

For an event :

Tag : GA (Universal Analytics)
Type : Event
Event category / action / label = you map your variables 
Reference field : screenName (your event must have a screen name parameter in Firebase to be mapped in this field otherwise it will return "undefined" value)